# Using ngStyle to assign style to a tr:first-child td

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-table

I get my data dynamically so it's always different.
I use `.replace` to add the `ngStyle` to a table, but how do I give the first-child, called td, a style?

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PI9DwqrtxL7oO1O3VWs?p=preview) so you can try something.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add a class using `ng-style`, something like this

```
<td ng-class="{'firstchild': 'someConditionGoesHere'}">Ali</td>
```

but to add a style to the first td, you ll have to stick with basic css like

```
.tableStyle td:first-child
```

what you can additionally do is add a class say 'test' using ng-style and have css definition like

```
.tableStyle td.firstchild:first-child {}
```

Mix of these would work out for you.